# How to convert nested Array into simple typescript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I have this information.I am looking to convert this array into typescript object.This object I generated from nested Object using Object.Keys and Object.Values.I try many options but it's look Object.keys and Object.Values only returns Arrays.Is something I am missing.

```
[
   {
      "value":[
         2.54,
         14.92,
         3.5,
         2.57,
         1.64,
         8.85,
         5.59,
         51.63,
         3.02,
         5.74
      ],
      "name":[
         "input",
         "output",
         "initialization",
         "pvtProperties",
         "rockProperties",
         "equationSetup",
         "networkWells",
         "solver",
         "update",
         "misc"
      ]
   }
]
```

I need to convert like this to show data into Chart.

```
data:[
        { value: 335, name: 'input' },
        { value: 335, name: 'output' },
        { value: 335, name: 'initialization' },
        { value: 335, name: 'pvtProperties' },
        { value: 335, name: 'rockProperties' },
        { value: 335, name: 'equationSetup' },
        { value: 335, name: 'networkWells' },
        { value: 335, name: 'solver' },
        { value: 335, name: 'update' },
        { value: 335, name: 'misc' }
      ];
```

Comment: What is the code you are having trouble with? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ? Please, provide a [mre]. Please be aware that [so] is not a code-writing service, you need to show your efforts!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let arr = [
   {
      value: [
         2.54,
         14.92,
         3.5,
         2.57,
         1.64,
         8.85,
         5.59,
         51.63,
         3.02,
         5.74
      ],
      name: [
         "input",
         "output",
         "initialization",
         "pvtProperties",
         "rockProperties",
         "equationSetup",
         "networkWells",
         "solver",
         "update",
         "misc"
      ]
   }
];

console.log(arr[0].value.map((v, i) => ({ value: v, name: arr[0].name[i] })));
```

Comment: It's giving me this error when I am using your solution.Cannot find module 'vis-data/esnext I think it's beacuse es2015.Any other approach

Comment: That error is not because of this line of code. As you can see this code does not rely on any module, it runs in the browser fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why each `value` is `335`, but here it is -

```js
const arr = [
   {
      "value":[
         2.54,
         14.92,
         3.5,
         2.57,
         1.64,
         8.85,
         5.59,
         51.63,
         3.02,
         5.74
      ],
      "name":[
         "input",
         "output",
         "initialization",
         "pvtProperties",
         "rockProperties",
         "equationSetup",
         "networkWells",
         "solver",
         "update",
         "misc"
      ]
   }
];
const data = arr[0].name.map(e => ({value: 335, name: e}));

console.log(data);
```